# Change the input value after a select change in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am looking for a way to select an option in my dropdown and to get the `data-item-price` and change the next `input.BOO_item_price` value by the value.

I have this:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered listItem">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <th width="20%">Quantity</th>
        <th width="50%">Item</th>
        <th width="20%">Price ($ CAN)</th>
        <th width="10%"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control BOO_item_quantity">
        </td>
        <td>
            <select class="form-control BOO_item_id">
                <option value="">Select</option>
                <option value="18" data-item-price="3">Coca</option>
                <option value="20" data-item-price="2">Sprite</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <input type="text" class="form-control BOO_item_price">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default removeItem"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have tried with this code:

```
$('select.BOO_item_id').on('change', function() {
    var price = $(this).find(':selected').data('item-price');
    $(this).children('input.BOO_item_price').val(price);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) look in immediate child nodes and `select` element doesn't have `input` as child thus your code didn't worked.

You need to use `this` current element context, traverse up to `tr` element using [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)/[`.parents()`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/). then use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to target `input` element

```
$('select.BOO_item_id').on('change', function() {
    var price = $(this).find(':selected').data('item-price');
    $(this).closest('tr').find('input.BOO_item_price').val(price);
});
```

Alternatively, You can also use

```
$(this).closest('td').next().find('input.BOO_item_price').val(price);
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply and for the details. It helps a lot. Your solution solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>parents()</kbd> will find first matched parent `tr` and then <kbd>find()</kbd> will find matched element in his child elements

```js
$('select.BOO_item_id').on('change', function() {
    var price = $(this).find(':selected').data('item-price');
   $(this).parents('tr').find('input.BOO_item_price').val(price);
  //$('input.BOO_item_price').val(price);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered listItem">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <th width="20%">Quantity</th>
        <th width="50%">Item</th>
        <th width="20%">Price ($ CAN)</th>
        <th width="10%"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control BOO_item_quantity">
        </td>
        <td>
            <select class="form-control BOO_item_id">
                <option value="">Select</option>
                <option value="18" data-item-price="3">Coca</option>
                <option value="20" data-item-price="2">Sprite</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <input type="text" class="form-control BOO_item_price">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default removeItem"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan right, need bit time to update things one by one.